# action_text - enable/disable attachments in different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, trix, actiontext

How can I disable action_text attachments for one field, but enable it for another?

I have a post model with 2 fields - `description_without_attachments` and `content_with_attachments`.

Model Post.rb:

```
  has_rich_text :description_without_attachments
  has_rich_text :content_with_attachments
```

I found that the following code if added into `packs/application.js` can block **all attachments** for trix action_text:

```
window.addEventListener("trix-file-accept", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  alert("File attachment not supported!")
})
```

however I want to block only for some specific field. I would imagine it working like:

```
  has_rich_text :description_without_attachments, attachments: false
```

Comment: looks like nobody cares about actiontext/trix more than I do...

Answer (score 4):

To do this in my project, I added the event listener on the editor specific to the field, not `window`.

In your case,

```js
let editor = document.querySelector('trix-editor#post_description_without_attachments');
editor.addEventListener("trix-file-accept", e => e.preventDefault());
```

(Although unnecessary due to the unique `id` attribute, I think using the `trix-editor` element name in the query selector better documents the code.)